# Is it safe to use a 27A battery instead of a 23A battery in my doorbell?

Tags: voltage, batteries, current, battery-operated

I have a device that says it takes a "23A 12V" battery. I ordered a new battery and was mistakenly sent a "27A 12V" battery; same voltage, higher current. Is it safe to use this battery in the device, or will it break things?

Apologies for what must seem like a noob question; I'm not an electronics person. I have found [a very similar question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/109827/can-i-use-batteries-of-higher-amperage) but it talks about capacity instead, and I'm not 100% sure whether that changes the answer or not.

Comment: Is your circuit fused to protect your wiring against extended over-current events?

Comment: Does it say 23A and 27A or 23Ah and 27Ah on the batteries?

Comment: Which device is in question?

Comment: @Justme it's a simple electronic doorbell. it does say A, not Ah.

Comment: A doorbell should not require 23 amps. Please give a link to product and manual. But this starts to look like how to use a product question.

Comment: @vvye: I suggest editing your question to "Is it safe to use an A27-type battery as a replacement for an A23-type battery" . Your issue has nothing to do with the current rating

Comment: @hilmar that is the question. Changing the title makes no sense.

Comment: @Passerby: but the OP completely misunderstands the battery labelling. So the question as asked has nothing to do with their actual problem/issue.

Comment: @hilmar so changing the question would do nothing for op and confuse it even more. The proper way to resolve it is as ocrdu did. Answer the question and problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The doorbell application gave it away: [23A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A23_battery) and [27A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A27_battery) refer to *types* of battery, not to amperes.

It's an unfortunate marking some manufacturers use for A23 and A27 batteries, also known under many other names.

A 27A is 8 mm x 28.2 mm, a 23A is 10.3 mm x 28.5 mm, and both are 12 V.

If it fits well in your doorbell, then use it, otherwise, return it.

Comment: Thanks so much, that was it! It was indeed an issue of battery types after all, not currents. The 27A one works well.